# Inform the other person that call will be recorded

Tags: android

I have created one application which records incoming and outgoing calls. But now i want to inform the person on the other end that the call will be recorded. Can anyone please tell me the possible ways by which I can inform this.

Comment: you have send sms backgroundly to otheend person

Comment: is it not required to inform the person before recording. SMS he will see after the conversation.

Comment: @Nisha I am dwelling at the same point. I wanted to create an app which should record both incoming and outgoing calls however upto this level, I am able to record voice on my side only if I turn off the speaker if its on, then I can record on both sides. What did you use to record voice at the other end? Please reply!!!

Answer (score 0):

The only practicle way to do this would be to send an SMS. Unless both subscribers have your app installed.

Comment: Informing the other person is a legal requirement in some Countries/States. I don't think SMS would be enough. SMS require cell phones with a SMS plan activated on it. Also in the US, cell phone numbers are indistinguishable from landline numbers (because of number portability and because they are charged the same as landlines unlike in Europe)

Comment: Stephan Branczyk then what according to u is the other alternative?

Comment: That the person on the phone say "This phone call is currently being recorded. Are you ok with that?". That would be the simplest. And your phone recorder could record that to serve as legal protection for the phone user. If the phone user still wants to record the conversation and doesn't say it, that's not your problem, that's his/her problem. He'll be the one going to jail (depending on the laws of the jurisdiction he's in). Another alternative would be to require the rooting of the phone, or to use yourself undocumented apis, but I don't know enough about those options to be of much help.

Comment: Actually, another alternative would be to use VOIP (Voice Over IP). You should be able to add sound to that.

Comment: Or better yet, use voice recognition to see if the phone owner says "I'm turning on voice recording right now" and then turn on the voice recorder after he said those magic words. And notify the phone owner with a small vibration that his command has been interpreted correctly.

Comment: VOIP would require a gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Unless both the users use your app, there is no way as David said. You could go with SMS, If not, you can consider **USSD**

Comment: Can u please tell me what is USSD?

Comment: USSD is not going to be an option for you. Most carriers don't allow device to device USSD communication. To effectively implement a USSD solution, you have to have contracts with the carriers.